# activitythread.performlaunchactivity(activitythread$activityclientrecord intent) source not found

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, manifest

then when i press f8 a  i get : ZygoteInit$methodandargscaller.run() source not found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.copyup"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.copyup.MainActivity"
        android:label="copy up" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>





     <activity 
        android:name=".Game"
        android:label="Copy Up">         
    </activity>
                    <activity 
        android:name=".Rules"
        android:label="Copy Up!">         
    </activity>
            <activity 
        android:name=".Scores"
        android:label="Copy Up!">         
    </activity>
                    <activity 
        android:name=".LearnCircle"
        android:label="Copy Up!">         
    </activity>
                            <activity 
        android:name=".LearnHoriz"
        android:label="Copy Up!">         
    </activity>
                            <activity 
        android:name=".LearnVert"
        android:label="Copy Up!">         
    </activity>
                            <activity 
        android:name=".LearnMenu"
        android:label="Copy Up!">         
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

and my code:

```
package com.example.copyup;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button start, rules, hs, learn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linktoxml();


start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    });
    /*
    rules.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Rules.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    });

    hs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scores.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    });

    learn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LearnMenu.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }

    });*/

    //show shape, take reading after 4 seconds, compare with other, if true   next, if false, end game
    //dont make it complex with time reduce yet!!
}


private void linktoxml() {
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcstart);
    rules = (Button) findViewById(R.id.brules);
    hs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhs);
    learn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blearn);

}
}
```

I have tried cleaning the project, re-writing the manifest and everything i can possible think of. It works if i comment out the links to the buttons in the code and leave them in the manifest but the moment i uncommnet them i get these errors, please help!!!

Comment: SOLVED! solved it, feeling pretty stupid now, needed bstart not bcstart when the button is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it, feeling pretty stupid now, needed bstart not bcstart when the button is defined.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Matteo - they're answering their own question, of course it provides an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the activity throw exception.
eclipse looks for the source code in android SDK and can't find it.

Just debug your code and find out where the code throw exception.

Comment: when i debug line by line i get the error in the title at "start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {"